# How can I make a close button with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am starting with JavaScript and I would like to make the close button close the *div* `.popup1` in this code:

https://jsfiddle.net/74hmx0vb/1

```
<div class='popup1' id="popup1">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row rowpopup">
      <div class="iconpopup">
        <img class="imgpopup" src="" />
      </div>
      <div class="textpopup">
        <div class="textpopup1">

        </div>
        <div class="textpopup2">

        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

I guess the best option is to make the close button call a function on click that adds a class with `display: none`. Is that right? I would also like to add a fadeout transition when the close button is clicked.

How can I do that? Is there a better option?

Comment: It will be fine to take a look at this video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ophW7Ask_0)

Comment: Start with trying to add a class. You can work on the transition after using css transitons

Answer (score 1):

That's right. A function that applies a class would work as you are looking for. In this case, you can have a function that applies a class when the close button is clicked like:

```js
var popupEl = document.querySelector( '. popup1' );
var button = document.querySelector( '.close' );

button.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
   popupEl.classList.add( 'closed' );
});
```

So your DOM will change into something like:

```html
<div class='popup1 closed' id="popup1">
....
```

In that sense, you can use opacity to hide and apply a transition into your element like:

```css
.popup {
   opacity: 1;
   transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
}

.closed {
   opacity: 0;
}
```

One last thing is that this will keep the element visible just with a hidden opacity. In order to remove it from the DOM or hide it completely, you can use `transitionend` to listen when the opacity transition has completed like:

```js
popupEl.addEventListener( 'transitionend', function(){
   popupEl.classList.add( 'removed ');
});

// css
.removed {
   display: none;
}
```

Be aware that `transitionend` will run in both directions. It means on `closed` applied or removed, so you need to make sure you are applying the `removed` class only when `closed` class is present on the element, like:

```js
popupEl.addEventListener( 'transitionend', function(){
   if( popupEl.classList.contains( 'closed' ) ) {
   popupEl.classList.add( 'removed ');
}
});
```

Comment: Leaving out punctuation makes it ***incomprehensible***. Please don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just use `display:none` in JavaScript without adding any classes:

**Using JavaScript:**

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById('popup1').style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.popup1 {
  height: 100px;
  width:300px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99999;
  background: white;
  bottom: 50px;
  left:50px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.45);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.45);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.45);

}

.rowpopup {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.textpopup {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: -15px;
}

.textpopup1 {
  font-size:16px;
}

.textpopup2 {
  font-size:14px;
}

.iconpopup {
  padding:10px;
}

.imgpopup {
  width:30px;
}

.hidepopup {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div class='popup1' id="popup1">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row rowpopup">
      <div class="iconpopup">
        <img class="imgpopup" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0076/6931/7690/files/clock2.png?8339" />
      </div>
      <div class="textpopup">
        <div class="textpopup1">
          Order as soon as possible
        </div>
        <div class="textpopup2">
          there is little time remaining for this deal to end
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="button"
      <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" class="close" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Or inline JavaScript code.**

```css
.popup1 {
  height: 100px;
  width:300px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99999;
  background: white;
  bottom: 50px;
  left:50px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.45);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.45);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.45);

}

.rowpopup {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.textpopup {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: -15px;
}

.textpopup1 {
  font-size:16px;
}

.textpopup2 {
  font-size:14px;
}

.iconpopup {
  padding:10px;
}

.imgpopup {
  width:30px;
}

.hidepopup {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div class='popup1' id="popup1">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row rowpopup">
      <div class="iconpopup">
        <img class="imgpopup" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0076/6931/7690/files/clock2.png?8339" />
      </div>
      <div class="textpopup">
        <div class="textpopup1">
          Order as soon as possible
        </div>
        <div class="textpopup2">
          there is little time remaining for this deal to end
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('popup1').style.display = 'none'" class="close" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's error in your code, so I will edit it.